# E-mail missing from callback

Tags: linkedin-api

We give our users the possibility to register to our platform using LinkedIn, so they can easily share some of their LinkedIn data on our platform and reduce the time it takes to create a profile. We ask for both `r_emailaddress` and `r_basicprofile`.

Sometimes, for very specific users, we don't get an e-mail address back from LinkedIn. This breaks our flow because it's a field we should be able to expect in the callback. And after all, we can't create a user without an e-mail address.

I've been trying to reproduce the scenario, with various scenarios that do and don't work.

#### Scenario 1

- User registers in one of the namespaces of our applications with e-mail visibility in their profile set to *"only 1st degree contacts"*.
- After registering, user sets their e-mail visibility to *"only me"*
- User registers to a 2nd namespace in the same application.
- E-mail is **empty**, the callback breaks (which means the user is asked to register manually).

#### Scenario 2

- User registers with e-mail visibility set to *"only me"*
- Registering succeeds.

So, having this setting set to "only me" seems to produce different results in 2 different scenarios. Is this a bug in LinkedIn or something we can somehow work around?